# Django bulk_create CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-models, create-view

I have my `models.py`

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_from = models.DateField('')
    date_to = models.DateField('', null=True)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

here my `views.py`

```
class Schedule(CreateView):
    fields = ()
    model = models.Schedule

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

and here my `template.html`

```
{{form.as_p}}
```

this form only can do 1 time input. however I need to perform 3 times input in single form with different name & date (in my case).

and form maybe look like

```
{{form.as_p}}    
{{form.as_p}}
{{form.as_p}}
```

I check on documentation theres bulk_create can do multiple input in single run but i dont have idea how to deal with my `template.html`

Comment: You should look into formsets, which is a way to work with multiple forms within the same template.

Comment: good, can you create give me an example on the answer,@Selcuk

Answer (score 4):

A demo for you:

views.py

```
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from .models import Schedule


class ScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = "__all__"


def multicreate(request):        
    if request.method == "POST":
        forms = [
            ScheduleForm(dict(name=n, date_from=df, date_to=dt, desc=ds))
            for n, df, dt, ds in zip(
                request.POST.getlist("name"),
                request.POST.getlist("date_from"),
                request.POST.getlist("date_to"),
                request.POST.getlist("desc"),
            )
        ]
        if all(forms[i].is_valid() for i in range(len(forms))):                
            for form in forms:
                form.save() 
            return HttpResponse(
                f"success to create {len(forms)} Schedule instances."
            )
    else:
        forms = [ScheduleForm() for _ in range(3)]
    return render(request, "create.html", {"forms": forms})
```

models.py

```
from datetime import date
from django.db import models


class Schedule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_from = models.DateField("date from", default=date.today)
    date_to = models.DateField("date to", default=date.today)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or self.__class__.__name__
```

template

```
<form method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
        {% for form in forms %}
                {{ form.Meta.model }} {{ forloop.counter }}<br>
                {{ form.as_p }}
                -------------------------------------------<br>
        {% endfor %}
<input type='submit', value='OK'>
</form>
```